# How do i check if a variable exist, in eex?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working on the crud part of a model, to which i've added image support to. Ideally i would like to show the image if you are editing a model, which i would do like this.

```
<%= Logo.url({@company.logo, @company}, :thumb) %>
```

The problem is that the company variable is only available in the edit action, as there are yet a company on the new action, so i need to check if the @company is set.

```
<%= unless @company do %>
  <%= Logo.url({@company.logo, @company}, :thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this yields the following error.

"assign @company not available in eex template. Available assigns: [:action, :changeset]"

I tried with is_nil, but same error.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**EDIT** Prior to [Phoenix 0.14.0](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/releases/tag/v0.14.0) `@company` would return nil if it was not set. It was changed to raise so that the assignment would be explicit (explicit over implicit.)

---

If you use either `@company` or `assigns.company` then an error will be raised. However if you use `assigns[:company]` then it will return nil if the value is not set.

```
<%= if assigns[:company] do %>
  <%= Logo.url({@company.logo, @company}, :thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

It is worth noting that if you are using a nested template then you will need to pass this through too:

```
<h1>New thing</h1>
<%= render "form.html", changeset: @changeset,
                        action: thing_path(@conn, :create),
                        company: assigns[:company] %>
```

Comment: The ideal though is to pass the company variable in. Even if it will be nil. It will avoid a bunch of indirection.

Comment: @JoséValim This is a good point - I'm going to add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The selected answer doesn't work.

Try with this :

```
<%= if Map.has_key?(assigns, :company) do %>
  <%= Logo.url({@company.logo, @company}, :thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The selected answer seems to be working as expected in Phoenix `1.4.16`. If `company` is set, the content is output; if it's not set, the content is not output, with no error.

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to work in LiveView templates.

Comment: I can't tell how it was in 2020 but in 2022 this works in LiveView templates