# Optional values in Elixir/Phoenix EEx shared templates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to pass values inside Phoenix EEx shared templates (templates that I reuse). So far, so good, but now I would like to make some of them mandatory and others optional. For example:

```
<a href="<=% @url %>" class="core Item <%= className %>">
```

- `url` should be mandatory - this is the default (OK);
- `className` should be optional - I can't make it because if I don't include it when calling the template 
  (`<%= render MyProject.SharedView, "myTemplate.html", url:"logo2.png" %>`)
  there's an error.
  How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `@class_name` (by convention variables should be written in snake_case) will raise if the key does not exist in `assigns`.

You can use `assigns[:class_name]` which will not raise if the key does not exist in `assigns` is not set.

Prior to [Phoenix 0.14.0](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/releases/tag/v0.14.0) `@company` would return nil if it was not set. It was changed to raise so that the assignment would be explicit (explicit over implicit.)

For this reason, you should also consider explicitly passing a nil class_name (As recommended in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412042/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exist-in-eex/32412097#comment52691690_32412097)):

```
<%= render MyProject.SharedView, "myTemplate.html", url:"logo2.png", class_name: nil %>
```